# How to use WKWebView in interface-builder?

Tags: ios, xcode7

How can we use WKWebView in interface builder in XCode 7? There is no instances of type WKWebView in object library.

Comment: You cant use it that way.You have to import webkit and add WKWebView to your view programmatically.